How to write grok expression for such log strings
My app logs are as shown below:
[2024-10-21 08:30:02] uat.INFO: Creating fake logs for testing purposes {"hostname":"my-host-6f5blah599-9p9kb","ip":"190.168.19.251","performance":29.680236}

[2024-10-21 08:33:57] uat.INFO: Creating simple fake logs for testing purposes


I am trying to write a GROK expression like:
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\] %{WORD:app_environment}.%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}[\s]?{%{GREEDYDATA:context}}

However it matches only the first line and not the second. How can I tweak it so that it can parse both the log lines?
P.S.:
I reviewed this question which explains "How do I make part of a regex match optional" but my requirement does not stop there; I want to capture whatever is inside the curly braces as a separate entity/field as "context" as shown in the screenshot.


Just make the last part optional since it may be present or not. \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\] %{WORD:app_environment}.%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}(?:\s{%{GREEDYDATA:context}})?

@WiktorStribiżew That does not parse whatever is in the curly brace as a separate entity & gets clubbed under message.

That is already a new "request", not a question. Your original question was how to match the optional final part of the pattern. Parsing the JSON data is not even related to regex already. Once you extract it, parse with the corresponding tools Grok provides.

@WiktorStribiżew I think you misunderstood what I am trying to say. By "That does not parse whatever is in the curly brace as a separate entity" I mean I want to capture whatever is in the curly braces under a field called "context" as shown in my original screenshot. Please let me know if still there is confusion to understand what I am trying to convey!

See this answer, link added to the list above.
